# how to make a compass with CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, core-location

I want to implement a compass into my app. I have looked at another stack overflow question and it said you can use the code below

This code in the viewDidLoad method

```
var lm:CLLocationManager!
   lm = CLLocationManager()
    lm.delegate = self
    lm.startUpdatingHeading()
```

And this function somewhere in the view controller

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {}
```

But when I run my code on the simulator, the function is not being called (and yes I did import CoreLocation and simulate a location). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this method for working then run the app in device or you can use a gpx file and simulate location in xcode terminal

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the simulator doesn't have a compass. You simply can't do that on the sim.

Second, I'm not sure if you have to ask the user's permission to get heading information. For GPS, you need both an entry in your info.plist and to make a call to request authorization. I haven't done heading code since the authorization requirement was added so I'm not sure if you have to do this for headings or not. A quick glance at the docs doesn't mention it.

I suggest consulting the Xcode docs on setting up heading updates:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH5-SW1

The key bit is this:

> To get heading events:
>
> Create a CLLocationManager object.
>
> Determine whether heading events are available by calling the headingAvailable class method.
>
> Assign a delegate to the location manager object.
>
> If you want true north values, start location services.
>
> Call the startUpdatingHeading method to begin the delivery of heading events.